# generic solution for showing message boxes, confirm boxes and etc

Tags: c#, silverlight

Confirm boxes(e.g. 'are you sure you want to delete selected file' with 'Yes', 'No' buttons. Or 'do you want to save before exit?' with 'Yes', 'No', 'Cancel' buttons) are thrown in any app. What is the best way to implement confirm boxes? Of cause one can create new dialog for each situation where confirm box is thrown, but maybe there's better solution?

Comment: Not "any app", some are sophisticated enough not to have to ask the user these "are you sure you know what you are doing?" questions.  However in the vast majority of apps pragmatically these questions are a necessary evil.  Sadly I've come across apps where these questions have had to be introduced though unnecessary because users have come to expect them and feel unnerved by not seeing them when they expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single dialog, pass it with custom enumeration, based on the enum value, build buttons dynamically, so on some enum value you will create buttons Ok, Cancel dynamically and on some enum value, you will create Yes, No, Cancel buttons. Hope this help.

Comment: hm. We come to similar conclusion.

Comment: Mark it as answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Such a comment might be acceptable on other forums and NGs but here it is considered bad form.  Only 25 minutes have past, give other people a chance. In the light of Eugeny89 existing 100% record the comment is also entirely unnecessary anyway.